# Show two columns in attribute form

Tags: qgis, qfield

I'm creating a QField project to field inventory land use.

I want to be able to see the old value and then update a new value in two columns in a form. Is there some way? Maybe if I create two layers, one with old values and one empty layer for storing the new ones? But how can I place them side by side in the Form layout?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to still store the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the old value ('Landuse'), I would use the old values for the new field ('Updated landuse') as a reference list in the attribute drag drop list (value map widget).

The new field would be editable using the existing list of values with drop down menu. And also maybe I would add the old value field as uneditable [image]

But if you want to have a proper solution witch stores the old values in history files and replaces it with new values, I would suggest using PostGIS in the background.

And for the parallel view of those two fields, you could use the the containers (click +button and add a new container as a tab : [image]